# Python Printing A List Issue

Tags: python, list, csv, urllib2, urlopen

I'm really struggling to work out how to print to a list. I'd like to print the server response codes of URLs I specify. Do you know how I'd alter to code to print the output into a list? If not, do you know where I'd find the answer? I've been searching around for a couple of weeks now.

Here's the code:

```
import urllib2
for url in ["http://stackoverflow.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"]:
    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print connection.getcode()
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.getcode()
```

prints:

```
200

200
```

I'd like to have:

```
[200, 200]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually want a list? Or just to print it like a list? In either case the following should work:

```
import urllib2
out = []
for url in ["http://stackoverflow.com/", "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/"]:
    try:
        connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        out.append(connection.getcode())
        connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        out.append(e.getcode())
print out
```

It just makes a list containing the codes, then prints the list.

Comment: Almost, you probably want to capture the code on Error as well.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed that part for you.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks to @sberry and Matthew Wesly for your quick responses!